# How to get a redirect url from a url using either curl or perl

Tags: perl, url, curl

Is there a way to get a redirected url either with a unix command or in perl.

I am writing a perl script to download mp3 files using curl. The url I start with redirects to another url. Currently I am manually entering the url into a browser and then copying the redirected url and entering that into my script.

I am a perl novice and my knowledge of the curl command is limited to:

curl -O http:blahblahblah.mp3.

The reason I am write a perl script is that there are many mp3 files with the url containing a file number which I am modifying in the script.

any constructive help is greatly appreciated.
thanks
john

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass a redirect, you should try :

```
curl -L domail.tld
```

if you want to display the redirected URL :

```
-w %{redirect_url}
```

Comment: WOW, THANKS! I thought I went through all of the options but didn't notice -L. Much thanks

Comment: Is there a way to have curl return the redirected url?

Comment: `curl --write-output redirect_url ...` looks like it will give you that.